# How do I declare lambda-style function name property in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, typescript, interface

I am using TypeScript 2.0 in a Node project. Functions in Node have a name property. I have tried extending the TypeScript Function interface to declare the property like so:

```
interface Function 
{
    name: string
}

interface IAsyncInfo {
    name: string,
    args: any[],
    func: (...args: any[]) => any
}

var info: IAsyncInfo;
var name = info.func.name
```

But TypeScript still complains on the last line:

```
Property 'name' does not exist on type (...args: any[]) => any
```

Then I tried:

```
var name = (info.func as Function).name
```

But TypeScript complains

```
type '(...args: any[]) => any' cannot be converted to type 'Function'
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what's going on, but your function doesn't have a name anyway.

Comment: Yes, but that is a runtime issue. TypeScript is complaining (at compile time) that the property is not declared, not that it is null or undefined at runtime

Comment: Yea that's the part I don't get :)

Comment: @prmph are you using resharper? I've found resharper to be absolutely atrocious with TypeScript 2.0. It will work fine with resharper disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you are trying.

Do you want something like this?

```
interface IAsyncInfo {
    name: string;
    args: any[];
    func(...args: any[]): any;
}

var info: IAsyncInfo;
var test = info.func.name;
```

Comment: That is an alternative way of declaring a variable as a function. But I just tried it and the error message is the same: "Property 'name' does not exist  on type '(...args: any[]): any'